# why sys.getsizeof returns the same output for very big lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

python version: **Python 3.6.0b3 (default, Nov 16 2016, 16:55:09)**

I have the following output:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof([0 for x in range(10**7)])
81528056
>>> sys.getsizeof([0 for x in range(10**8)])
859724472
>>> sys.getsizeof([0 for x in range(10**8+100500)])
859724472
>>> sys.getsizeof([0 for x in range(10**9)])
8058558880

Length of lists:
>>> len([0 for x in range(10**8)])
100000000
>>> len([0 for x in range(10**8+100500)])
100100500
>>>
```

Why did I have the same `getsizeof`output for lists which len are:
`10**8` and `10**8+100500` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a [list is resized](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.6.0b3/Objects/listobject.c#l26) larger its length is increased by [a bit more than 1/8 of the requested length](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.6.0b3/Objects/listobject.c#l49). 100500 is far less than 1/8 of 10**8 which means that the list likely doesn't need to be resized from its previous resize in order to accommodate the new entries.

Comment: But why it's resizing ? Each line creates a new list

Comment: Because the list comprehension is pulling entries from the `range` object one at a time, which results in deterministic behavior.

Comment: I've tried to run these 2 commands in separate terminals, result was the same.

Comment: Yes, that's what "deterministic" means.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sys.getsizeof shows the size in byte. Your lists with [0 for x in range(10**8...)]) can both be displayed with 859724472 bytes.